# problems with Arch linux installation commands

Tags: archlinux

It's my first time trying to install and using Arch linux, I was trying to install it in VirtualBox in Mac Os mojave, when i did `arch-chroot /mnt`(after all the configuration), then tried to `nano /etc/locale.conf` it just printed `command not found`.

I've already tried with `vim` or other commands like `sudo` or `apt` to install a plain text editor but it's always the same and I also tried twice but nothing changes.

PLEEAAASE, I need help.

Comment: Did you explicitly install nano during the installation? You have to do this explicitly since a few months. Actually the english installation guide doesn't tell you, but the german does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Archlinux you should use pacman -S to install packages
try this :
"pacman -S nano"

you can see more information here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman#Installing_packages

Comment: Seems like he didn't installed Nano.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it with the Linux kernel etc.
For installing the kernel you use

> ***pacstrap***

so just add nano, vim or whatever text-editor you like to use.

For more information: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide